# How to call Javascript in href in main window from iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hyperlink, anchor

I have a hyperlink in the iframe.

```
<a href="JavaScript:openRec('8888')">Click here</a>
```

In the parent window I have a script in which the `openRec` function is declared. How can I call this function from the iframe?

Comment: Do simple with parent js script link with in your head of the iframe html `<script src="parent.js"></script>` .Because Its already declare as a function in your parent .

Comment: I cannot do that because that code is actually native code

Comment: If you're after this kind of interaction, iframes are probably not the way to go about it.

Comment: Depends on the domain. If they are seperate domains, you probably can't and should reverse the logic so the parent controls the iframe, not the other way around. So the parent should edit the iframe, since the iframe can't call any functions inside the parent. If they are the same domain, why use an iframe anyway?

Comment: I my requirement to use iframe in same domain. If you have any solution then tell us

Comment: @KushalJain It's just that iframes bring many constraints with css and js. In the long run you would make your life easier with something serverside like php include, or maybe even html import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent

```
 <a onclick="parent.openRec('8888');" href="#" >Click here</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="JavaScript:parent.openRec('8888');" >Click here</a>
```

this should work if parent window and iframe belongs to same domain.

It may not work in cross-domain scenario.

Comment: yes it belongs to same domain and what is the difference if I pass parent.openRec in href ?

Comment: You can do that also

Comment: when I put <a href="parent.openRec('888')">click here</a> it concat to my domain link like http://127.0.0.1/myapp/parent.openRec('888')

Comment: its not called my javascript function, it work as a hyperlink mean redirect to url

Comment: Try <a href="JavaScript:parent.openRec('8888');" >Click here</a>